# How can I set timeout for KafkaConsumer if the broker's address is incorrect, there are no messages in topic, or the topic is missing?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have this method working good. Through this method I am able to grab messages from certain Kafka topic.

```
public List<MessageResponseDTO> getMessagesFromTopic(String topicName, Properties properties) {
    List<MessageResponseDTO> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    try (KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)) {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1000));//returns immediately if there are records available. Otherwise, it will await (loop for timeous ms for polling)
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> recordMessage : records) {;
            String value = recordMessage.value();
            String formattedDate = getFormattedDateFromTimeStamp(recordMessage);
            MessageResponseDTO buildMessage = MessageResponseDTO.builder().message(value).date(formattedDate).build();
            messages.add(buildMessage);
        }
    }
    return messages;
}
```

The problem occurs when I enter an incorrect broker address.

logs below

```
2021-10-09 13:39:55.723  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.0.74:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:39:55.724  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9095 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:39:57.865  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -2 (/192.168.0.74:9096) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:39:57.866  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9096 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:39:59.999  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -3 (/192.168.0.74:9097) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:39:59.999  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9097 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:02.133  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.0.74:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:02.133  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9095 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:04.282  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -2 (/192.168.0.74:9096) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:04.282  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9096 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:06.437  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -3 (/192.168.0.74:9097) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:06.437  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9097 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:08.570  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.0.74:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:08.570  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9095 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:10.706  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -2 (/192.168.0.74:9096) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:10.706  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9096 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:12.843  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -3 (/192.168.0.74:9097) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:12.843  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9097 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:14.991  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.0.74:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:14.991  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9095 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:40:17.161  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -2 (/192.168.0.74:9096) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:40:17.161  WARN 5020 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-1, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9096 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
```

I have to wait each time about 80 seconds, when counsumer will be closed and method returns 0 messages. How can I set the timeout on the consumer so that it doesn't wait 80 seconds each time but, for example, reduce the time to 5 seconds?

I mean something like...

consumer.setTimeoutForBroker(example)

Here is also my configuration file

```
private Properties prepareProperties(String brokerAddressByConnectionName) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", brokerAddressByConnectionName);
    props.put("group.id", "consumer-test-group-spring-boot");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return props;
}
```

Another problem is that if I enter a good brokers address but the wrong topic then consumer will create a topic and start listening and return a timeout only after 80 seconds. Is it possible to shorten this timeout using configuration?

logs below

```
2021-10-09 13:44:53.169  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.7.1
2021-10-09 13:44:53.169  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 61dbce85d0d41457
2021-10-09 13:44:53.169  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1633779893169
2021-10-09 13:44:53.169  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Subscribed to topic(s): TestTopic312
2021-10-09 13:44:55.200  WARN 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -1 (/192.168.0.74:9091) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:44:55.201  WARN 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9091 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:44:57.342  WARN 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Connection to node -3 (/192.168.0.74:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-10-09 13:44:57.342  WARN 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Bootstrap broker 192.168.0.74:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2021-10-09 13:44:57.475  WARN 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {TestTopic312=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
2021-10-09 13:44:57.475  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Cluster ID: pEMDApYNT9a6zyYgPfzEdQ
2021-10-09 13:44:57.484  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Discovered group coordinator 192.168.0.74:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null)
2021-10-09 13:44:57.485  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-09 13:44:57.493  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] (Re-)joining group
2021-10-09 13:44:57.500  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=1, memberId='consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3-a40c2b95-6068-4806-8a65-370455d9001a', protocol='range'}
2021-10-09 13:44:57.593  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3-a40c2b95-6068-4806-8a65-370455d9001a=Assignment(partitions=[TestTopic312-0])}
2021-10-09 13:44:57.598  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=1, memberId='consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3-a40c2b95-6068-4806-8a65-370455d9001a', protocol='range'}
2021-10-09 13:44:57.598  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Notifying assignor about the new Assignment(partitions=[TestTopic312-0])
2021-10-09 13:44:57.598  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Adding newly assigned partitions: TestTopic312-0
2021-10-09 13:44:57.601  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Found no committed offset for partition TestTopic312-0
2021-10-09 13:44:57.604  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Resetting offset for partition TestTopic312-0 to position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[192.168.0.74:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)], epoch=0}}.
2021-10-09 13:46:33.176  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Revoke previously assigned partitions TestTopic312-0
2021-10-09 13:46:33.176  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3, groupId=consumer-test-group-spring-boot] Member consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3-a40c2b95-6068-4806-8a65-370455d9001a sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 192.168.0.74:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed
2021-10-09 13:46:33.181  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics scheduler closed
2021-10-09 13:46:33.181  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2021-10-09 13:46:33.181  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Metrics reporters closed
2021-10-09 13:46:33.183  INFO 14500 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : App info kafka.consumer for consumer-consumer-test-group-spring-boot-3 unregistered
```

My main goal which I would like to achieve is that the user should not wait more than one minute only so that I can manually set timeout in a bad broker address or no message on a topic which de facto does not exist... .

Comment: There's a metadata timeout config. Have you tried it?

Comment: yep,I tried with
session.timeout.ms and request.timeout.ms which seemed reasonable

Comment: at the moment I am not able to solve this issue via configuration,  maybe it's just the way it's supposed to be, in the sense of not interfering with that behavior

Comment: Maybe not via a consumer (or KafkaListener annotation), but you can use AdminClient to try and describe the cluster before setting up a consumer

Comment: Good point, I should check the client admin if the cluster is ok, maybe store a flag about it somewhere, then run the consumer, I will try this solution! 

p.s was thinking about setting a timeout for the method execution, in the sense if consumer returns nothing for 5 seconds then close it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement brokers and topics that detect errors in time? What are the broker parameters? If you just want to find wrong topics and brokers, you can set "auto.create.topics.enable=false". When the topic does not exist, an error will be reported.

Comment: The error will be in the consumer logs, though, not an exception _to the client_ that halts the poll-loop